# Android Amazon SNS Invalid Parameter

Tags: android, amazon-sns

Code Returns Exception Invalid Paramters 
I need to know what are the invalid params ? 
Is Application ARN string value from where to get it or it is a static value . 
when to send device if returned from GCM ?

```
    CreatePlatformEndpointRequest cpeReq =
                new CreatePlatformEndpointRequest();

    cpeReq.setCustomUserData("");
    cpeReq.setToken(this.mToken);
    cpeReq.setPlatformApplicationArn(retrieveEndpointArn());

    client.setRegion(Region.getRegion(Regions.DEFAULT_REGION));


    CreatePlatformEndpointResult cpeRes = client
            .createPlatformEndpoint(cpeReq);
    endpointArn = cpeRes.getEndpointArn();
} catch (InvalidParameterException ipe) {
    String message = ipe.getErrorMessage();
    System.out.println("Exception message: " + message);
    Pattern p = Pattern
            .compile(".*Endpoint (arn:aws:sns[^ ]+) already exists " +
                    "with the same  Token.*");
    Matcher m = p.matcher(message);
    if (m.matches()) {
        // the endpoint already exists for this token, but with
        // additional custom data that
        // CreateEndpoint doesn't want to overwrite. Just use the
        // existing endpoint.
        endpointArn = m.group(1);
    } else {
        // rethrow exception, the input is actually bad
        throw ipe;
    }
}
```

Comment: It will be useful to help if you could post the exception message that you get.

Comment: Invalid parameter: PlatformApplicationArn Reason: no value for required parameter